# windows 10 Mail won't render max-width

Tags: css, windows

I have this script for my email template:

```
<tr style="margin: 0;padding: 0;font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, &quot;Helvetica&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size: 100%;line-height: 1.6">
    <td style="max-width: 110px;text-align: center;padding: 10px;margin: 0;font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, &quot;Helvetica&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size: 100%;line-height: 1.6">
     <img style="max-width: 110px;margin: 0;padding: 0;font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, &quot;Helvetica&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size: 100%;line-height: 1.6" src="{{url(asset(isset($email_logo) ? $email_logo : 'assets/images/logo-dark.png'))}}" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
```

The problem here is that Windows 10 Mail App won't render the CSS properly. This is not the only part of the template it doesn't render properly as well.

The template works fine for Gmail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mail clients do not support many modern CSS or HTML features well or at all. To support clients like Outlook or Win mail, you should revert to the simplest, oldest possible HTML (basically just table elements with width-attributes on td elements) and only use more advanced CSS to progressively enhance the message for clients like Gmail and maybe responsiveness for mobile clients.

Here's a great resource of what you can use in which clients:
https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/box-model/max-width

Answer (score 1):

While looking for answer related to Windows 10 Mail App, I found this useful solution which we can to style our email specific to Outlook/Mail App using VML (Vector Markup Language)

https://email.uplers.com/blog/email-rendering-issues-in-outlook-and-hacks/

I hope it can be helpful to someone.